# Prove that $f$ belongs to $B(X,\mathbb C)$ and evaluate $\Vert f \Vert$.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, functional-equations

Let $t_1,\ldots,t_n\in[a,b]$, $c_1,\ldots,c_n\in\mathbb C$ and define a linear functional $f(x)=\sum_{j=1}^nc_jx(t_j)$ on $X$, where $X=C([-1,1], \mathbb C)$, the complex-valued continuous functions on the finite symmetric interval $[-1,1]$ of $\mathbb R$. Prove that $f$ belongs to $B(X,\mathbb C)$ and evaluate $\Vert f \Vert$.

This is a homework question from my functional analysis class.

In my opinion, to prove that $f$ belongs to $B(X,\mathbb C)$, firstly we have to show that $f$ is linear and secondly $f$ is bounded which is to show that $f$ is continuous.

I am just wondering if my fundamental method is correct?

Comment: @ThomasShelby On the homework sheet, there is not restrictions on $a$ and $b$ at all.

Comment: Well, if $[a,b]\not\subseteq [-1,1]$, then there might be some $y\in[a,b]$ for which $x(y)$ is not defined.

Comment: BTW, your outline of the proof is fine. Don't forget to evaluate $\|f\|$:)